# Factorize a composite number

Tags: number-theory, factoring

Is the following true?

> Let $n$ be a composite number in base $b$.
>
> a) Let $R$ be the rational period of $\frac{1}{n}$ in base $b$. This number is of length $k$ where $k$ in turn is also a composite number, substantially smaller than $n$;
>
> b) Choose a non-trivial divisor $d$ of $k$ and calculate $R' = R \ (\text{mod } b^d-1)$;
>
> c) Calculate $M = \gcd(R', b^d-1)$;
>
> d) Calculate $P = (b^d-1)/M$.
>
> Then $P$ is a prime factor of $n$.

---

For example let $n=1259879$. Then $\frac{10^{35}-1}{n} = 79372701664207435793437306281$

$1$) $$R \ (\text{mod } 10^7-1) = 6900408 \\
\gcd(9999999,6900408) = 2151 \\
\frac{9999999}{2151} = 4649$$

$2$) $$R \ (\text{mod } 10^5-1) = 83394 \\
\gcd(99999,83394) = 369\\
\frac{99999}{369} = 271$$

$$\rightarrow 271 \cdot 4649 = 1259879$$

Comment: This is hard to read.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm asking whether there's something wrong with it. As I understand the problem of factorizing a composite number into its prime factors is a problem of some importance.

Comment: How do you propose to find $k$ without knowing the prime factorisation of $n$, or performing the base $b$ division, $1/n$? If $n$ happens to be prime, $k$ can be as high as $n-1$. Sure, many composites have shorter periods, but the period can still be rather high for prime powers & semiprimes. Eg, the period in base 10 of 323=17×19 is 144.

Comment: This algorithm is meant for composite n alone. In case k is even you can change the base to b to the 2 over and over until the period is odd. This method just simplify the problem of factorization by replacing n with a generally much shorter k.